# Avoiding multiple If statements

Tags: apex, code

Is there a better way in Apex to have multiple If Statements? I know that multiple if statements will slow performance, and my scenario would require me to have 36 different scenarios.

Ex:

I have 2 objects with 2 fields each on them.  Each of those fields has 3 possible values (0,X,Y). So line 1 of the 36 lines I'd need would look like :

```
if(obj1.field1 == 0 && obj1.field2 == 0 && obj2.field1 == 0 && obj2.field2 == 0){
  ///////scenario 1 logic
} 
if(scenario 2 conditions){
  /////scenario 2 
}
```

and so on until all conditions are covered. Is a switch statement my only real option, or can this be solved in a different way?

Comment: Why is there 36 different scenarios? I think I read switch statements are actually slower

Comment: if the tests are all equalities, then create a map using concatenated key => true/false then simply generate the concatenated key and do a lookup in map to get result

Comment: @cropredy I am going to try that tonight and will report back

Comment: A word of caution bout assumptions on performance: it only matters inside big tight loops so the other 99% of the time it doesn't matter and you should instead focus on making your code understandable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's assume that all tests are equalities

You could create a simple two-level map. Note that map keys can be sobjects. The map key will be an sobject possessing only the fields+vals for a given combination to evaluate.  I chose a two level map to make it easier to setup as there are two sobjecttypes involved in the OP.

```
// define map (most likely static) of all 36 branches.  
// Map is a map of maps where the leftmost key is the first SobjectType and
// and the rightmost key is a map of the second sobjecttype
static Map<Object1__c,Map<Object2__c,Boolean>> evaluator = 
  new Map<Object1__c,Map<Object2__c,Boolean>> {
   new Object1__c(F1__c = 'a', F2__c = 'b') =>
     new Map<Object2__c,Boolean> {
        new Object2__c(G1__c = 'x', G2__c = 'y') => false,
        new Object2__c(G1__c = 'w', G2__c = 'y') => true,
        ... enumerate all possible combos of G1 and G2 in Object2 (6 total)
     },
   new Object1__c(F1__c = 'a', F2__c = 'c') =>
     new Map<Object2__c,Boolean> {
        new Object2__c(G1__c = 'x', G2__c = 'y') => true,
        new Object2__c(G1__c = 'w', G2__c = 'y') => true,
        ... enumerate all possible combos of G1 and G2 in Object2 (6 total)
     }, 
   ... for remaining combos of values F1, F2 in Object1 (4 more)
};
```

Then your code to evaluate for false/true is simply

```
private Boolean evaluate(Object f1,Object f2, Object g1, Object g2) {
 // Build lookup keys from inputVals to method
 Object1__c primaryKey = new Object1__c(F1__c = f1, F2__c = f2);
 Object2__c secondaryKey = new Object2__c(G1__c = g1, G2__c = g2);


 return evaluator.containsKey(primaryKey) // entry for Object1 ?
    ? evaluator.get(primaryKey).containsKey(secondaryKey) // yes, entry for Object2 ?
      ? evaluator.get(primaryKey).get(secondaryKey) // yes, get result t/f
      : false // nope, default to false
    : false;  // nope, default to false
 }
```

and you would invoke by

```
evaluate(10,'abc',67,'xyz');  // args would of course be vbls populated 
                             //  from some input like json or VF controller or trigger
```

Code coverage is trivial although it would be a good idea to test that you set up your evaluator map with the expected results; The test method merely needs to generate 36 inputs and verify against an expected results list

This could be generalized to put the evaluator map in custom metadata as a JSON object that you could at runtime deserialize (or as a list of custom metadata that you read and build the evaluator dynamically)

*N.B. if tests are inequalities or the range of fields used to test are not consistent, then the above pattern breaks*

Comment: this seems like a pattern that I could use when I code, and is more elegant than what I was going to suggest. I tried playing around with it in my dev console, but I'm really having a really, really hard time understanding it. Would you have some time to break the code, and the approach down?

Comment: @ohana - updated

Comment: @cropredy thank you for the solution, I ended up substituting a string instead of a boolean in the map so I could provide further logic after a match had been made. Also I think "Object2__c secondaryKey = new Object1__c(G1__c = g1, G2__c = g2);" is a typo and should have Object2__c instead of Object1__C

Comment: @MikeMeadows - fixed typo - thanks

Comment: P.S. Optimized return statement: `return evaluator.containsKey(primaryKey) && evaluator.get(primaryKey).containsKey(secondaryKey) && evaluator.get(primaryKey).get(secondaryKey);`

Comment: @sfdcfox. Brilliant!